# How to change style from code? Want to achieve skins

Tags: android, skinning

How to change a style from code?

I got a style used all across my app, for all buttons. If the user changes the skin of the app, the background of this style should change.

```
<style name="ActionBtn">
    <item name="android:layout_width">@dimen/action_btn_width</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">@dimen/action_btn_height</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/btn_frame_bgstate</item>
    <item name="android:padding">@dimen/action_btn_padding</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin">@dimen/action_btn_margin</item>
</style>
```

So far the only idea I got is to make a custom button that itself chooses its background on creation.

I have not found any good, generic way for skinning android apps yet, but if I could change styles from code, that would do the trick.

All suggestions welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Create different themes for your skins.

2) Set those themes programatically using following code in your `onCreate` method.

```
setTheme(resid);
```

resid is the id of your theme.

Comment: Yes, so do you have any idea how to implement that kind of scenario?